# JMeter DNS Cache manager not working when adding multiple IP adressess for one host

Tags: dns, jmeter, multiple-entries

I'm building a JMeter testplan for a NLB farm. In order to get the JMeter test users to all servers in the NLB farm I'm using the DNS Cache Manager (otherwise all tests will go to one server of the farm). I've created multiple Static Host Table entries with the same URL, but each with a unique IP address (e.g.: bla.url.com -> 10.10.10.10 bla.url.com -> 10.10.10.11, etc.)

But all test sessions go to the first entry in the host table instead of "round robin" around the multiple entries.

I've tried the following:
- Used system host file instead of DNS cache manager
- Enabled clear cache each iteration in DNS cache manager
- Disabled Java cache in Java security properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misusing the DNS Cache Manager, `Static Host Table` feature is basically implementation of the [`hosts` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) where you can add IP addresses to hostnames mapping just in case you cannot do it on operating system level (i.e. due to lack of admin rights).

For particular your scenario it would be just enough to simply add the DNS Cache Manager to your Test Plan to enable per-thread DNS resolution instead of relying on underlying Java/operating system implementations. And you should specify a single entry point like hostname of your [load balancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) instead of listing all the backend hostnames under the static host table.

More information: [The DNS Cache Manager: The Right Way To Test Load Balanced Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps/)

Comment: Thanks for you reply and the more info link!

The problem in my situation is that the NLB is configured in such a way that balancing is done based on the source IP address. In other words; the machine that creates the test-load will always be routed to the same NLB node.

I'm now thinking if (and how) it would be possible to create a variable with multiple values (eg: variable URL with values server1, server2, server3, server4), than let JMeter loop through these values and use the variable as the DNS Cache Manager hostname...

Comment: If you need to amend the source IP address you're looking into wrong configuration element, you need to put the desired IP address into "Source Address" input which is under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler: https://i.stack.imgur.com/huY4V.png. The technique is known as [IP Spoofing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter/). You can also use a JMeter Variable originating i.e. from CSV Data Set Config there.

Comment: hi Dmitri,

Thanks, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for since I'm not able to control which source IP is routed to which NLB node (this is done by another department in the IT organization).

What I really need is a way to give multiple values to one variable so each time JMeter looks up the variable it will get back one of the values.

I've now created 1 entry in the DNS cache manager (test.url.com) with a variable name as hostname (${var1}). This works, last step is to make sure that {var1} returns a different value on each iteraion (an array or CSV, etc.)

Comment: Dmitri, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! The final solution that worked for me:
- DNS Cache Manager with settings; clear cache on each iteration, 1 host entry with a variable as hostname/ip address. A CSV data set config with the NLB nodes in it.